# Non alphanumeric characters in R

Tags: r

For uppercase, lowercase letters and 10-digits I can generate a vector that contains all letters or 10-digit number as follow:

```
A <- LETTERS[0:26]
B <- letters[0:26]
C <- seq(0,9)
```

I wonder whether there is a similar function for non-alphanumeric characters.

```
~!@#$%^&*_-+=`|\(){}[]:;"'<>,.?/
```

I tried

```
D <- c("~","!","@","#","$","%","^", "&","*","_","-","+","=","`","|","\","(",")","{","}","[","]",":",";",""","'","<",">",",",".","?","/")
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi @RichardScriven, sorry that i not really get it.

Comment: If you want all ascii characters, `rawToChar(as.raw(1:127), multiple=T)` should work. It's unclear what exactly how you are choosing your list. There are many characters that are non-printable. Plus it depends on your particular encoding. You may have more characters in the extended pages and encodings like UTF-8 define many, many more character codes.

Comment: What are you trying to actually do? There are several characters in there that would need to be escaped (with `\\\`) if you want to store them in a vector.

Comment: rawToChar(as.raw(c(32:47, 58:64,91,93:96,123:126)), multiple=T) is what i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is another option. Generate all ascii characters, then filter out the non punctuation with regular expressions.

```
ascii <- rawToChar(as.raw(0:127), multiple=TRUE)
ascii[grepl('[[:punct:]]', ascii)]

# [1] "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "."  "/"  ":"  ";"  "<"  "="  ">"  "?"  "@" 
# [23] "["  "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "{"  "|"  "}"  "~"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful . . The ASCII character set is arranged in ranges of similar types of characters (letters, etc).

http://datadebrief.blogspot.com/2011/03/ascii-code-table-in-r.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit drawn out, and there's probably a better website (and a better way to get the same result), but

```
library(XML); library(RCurl)
doc <- htmlParse(getURL("https://wci.llnl.gov/codes/basis/manual/node161.html"))
xp <- xpathSApply(doc, "//tr/td", xmlValue, trim = TRUE) 
xp[nzchar(xp) & nchar(xp) == 1]
#  [1] "!" "[" "%" "," "]" "&" "-" "|" "'" "." "=" "~" "("
# [14] "/" ")" "*" "=" "{" "?" "`" "}" "@" ":" ";" "^" " "
```

Also, using the website from the other answer yields a more complete result

```
> URL <- "http://datadebrief.blogspot.com/2011/03/ascii-code-table-in-r.html"
> r <- readLines(URL, warn = FALSE)[780:874]
> s <- sapply(strsplit(r, "\\s+"), "[", 1) 
> s[!s %in% c(letters, LETTERS, 0:9)]
#  [1] ""     "!"    "\""   "#"    "$"    "%"    "&"    "'"    "("   
# [10] ")"    "*"    "+"    ","    "-"    "."    "/"    ":"    ";"   
# [19] "<"    "="    ">"    "?"    "@"    "["    "\\\\" "]"    "^"   
# [28] "_"    "`"    "{"    "|"    "}"    "~"
```

...or yeah, just use `rawToChar(as.raw(...))` like MrFlick said :-)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is only for amusement, list the characters you want and use `strsplit` to generate your vector.

```
> D <- strsplit('!"#$%&\'()*+,-./\\:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~', '(?=.)', perl=T)[[1]]
##  [1] "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "."  "/" 
## [16] "\\" ":"  ";"  "<"  "="  ">"  "?"  "@"  "["  "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "{"  "|" 
## [31] "}"  "~"
```

Or filter the characters you want.

```
> D <- gsub('[^\\pP\\pS]', '', rawToChar(as.raw(1:127), multiple=T), perl=T)
> D[D != ""]
##  [1] "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "."  "/" 
## [16] ":"  ";"  "<"  "="  ">"  "?"  "@"  "["  "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "{"  "|" 
## [31] "}"  "~"
```